# Windows NtBackup on Vista/2008

Tags: windows, backup

It is apparently possible to run the older ntbackup on [Vista](http://www.petri.co.il/installing_windows_xp_ntbackup_on_windows_vista.htm).  Does anyone have experience using this?  Is this reliable?  Are their problems?  Is this possible on Windows 2008?

Comment: I thought the idea was you could restore from ntbackup on vista/2008 but not back up with the older utility?. Haven't any personal experience though.

Comment: Note that Windows 7 & 2008 R2 will no longer support the installation of RSM, thus there will be no NTBackup at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the following DLL's over to do this:

- ntbackup.exe
- Ntmsapi.dll
- Vssapi.dll

You will also need to add the Removable Storage Management component to Vista for it to work, to do so go to control panel-> programs and click on turn on windows features.

As renniej said, this will only backup to disk and not to tape.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it on Vista, but the old NTBackup does run on Server 2008 provided you copy a few dlls. I forget which dlls are needed, but just run the ntbackup.exe from 2k3 and it will say which dlls it can't find. In fact if you copy the Exchange dlls it will even back up your Exchange 2007 store.

However it will only backup to a file. The 2k3 NTBackup relies on the Removeable Storage Service to manage the tapes. RSM isn't installed by default on 2k8. You can install it (it's under Features) but even with RSM installed NTBackup reports it can't connect to RSM. Note that this was the 32 bit NTBackup on x64 2k8 (I think I did try the NTBackup copied from an x64 2k3 installation, but I can't be sure.)

Note that MS supply a version of NTBackup that will work on Server 2008, but it will only do restores. You can't use it for backups. It seems a silly situation, but I think Vertitas wrote NTBackup and there may be licencing problems that stopped MS from including it in 2008/Vista. Maybe tape backup will gradually cease to be used, but for now t means the extra expense of buying Backup Exec.

John Rennie